# How to request administrator permissons only on release builds?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

**Description:** I want my application to request administrator permissions only when it is compiled using my Release configuration. The main reason for it is that I do not need the administrator permission when debugging/developing the app, but it requires administrator permission when delivered.

Currently I only use the *app.manifest* file for requesting the administrator permissions with the following code:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

**Now to my question:** Where in my project file (*name.csproj*) do I have to include the *app.manifest* file in order to only embed it when I'm using my "Release" configuration?

I use the following code to include the *app.manifest* file inside the project file:

```
<ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After taking another look at my project file I figured out where to put it.

**Answer:** Inside the following *PropertyGroup* in the project file (*name.csproj*), which represents the *"Release"* build,
you have to put the following code to include the *app.manifest* file:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    ...
    <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This allows to only request administrator rights on *"Release"* builds.
It can also be added on other build configurations as well.